# Why automatic line-break of flexbox child increases it's width while using manual <br/> doesn't?

Tags: css, flexbox, line-breaks

As you can see the element containing "Hello World!" takes up more width in the first example than in the second one. Why is that and how can I make it take the same amount of width as in the second example?

```html
<div style="width: 80px">
    <div style="display:flex;">
      <div style="background: orange">Hello World!</div>
      <div>1</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <br />
  <br />

  
  <div style="width: 80px">
    <div style="display:flex;">
      <div style="background: orange">Hello <br /> World!</div>
      <div>2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: The reason is that a container does not know when a child element wraps, so it doesn't shrink-to-fit.

Answer (score 0):

it because you are breaking the line before the given width

you can add border and check

```css
.one, .two {
 border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 80px" class="one">
    <div style="display:flex;">
      <div style="background: orange">Hello World!</div>
      <div>1</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <br />
  <br />

  
  <div style="width: 80px" class="two">
    <div style="display:flex;">
      <div style="background: orange">Hello <br> World!</div>
      <div>2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: In the second example I'm also breaking the line before the given width and don't get the same effect.